# Array of structure equivalent in golang

Tags: c, arrays, struct, go

I am looking for something equivalent to array of structures. Or something equivalent to the following code in golang:

```
struct my_struct {
     int a;
     char b;
}ins[10],*p[10];
```

Any example, how can I feed/assign values to these in golang?

Comment: Please be more specific in your questions. Good question should include problem statement and demonstrate your effort in solving it.

Comment: What do you need exactly?

Comment: @ I m trying to parse command line arguments using cli library. And need to pass list options and their help to App.name/usage in a loop.
By the way, as part of my effort:
var login = []struct {
          long_opt  string
          help_data string
  }{
          {"username, u", "Requires name of the user"},
          {"password, p", "Requires password"},
          {"Server, s", "Server Name"},
 }
But it is difficult this way. So posted a question here. I don't find any example like this on the google though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some basic info on arrays: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#arrays

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var s [10]MyStruct //initializes to 0

func main() {
    for k, v := range s {
        fmt.Println(k, v.a)
    }
}

type MyStruct struct {
    a int64
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// define structure type
type my_struct struct {
  a int
  b rune
}

// declare slice of my_struct
var a []my_struct

// declare and initialise struct with one element 
b := make([]my_struct, 1)

// create structure and save it
b[0] = my_struct{1, 'a'}

// append a new one
b = append(b, my_struct{2, 'b'})
```

You definitely have to read https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html, especially about structs and slices if you want to know more about them.